# Remote Event receiver using provider hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-hosted-app, provider-hosted-app, remote-event-receiver

Getting error on deploy Remote event receiver using provider hosted app solution in SharePoint online.

```
Cannot register Services/RemoteEventReceiver1.svc on Microsoft Azure Service Bus: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
One or more services were unregistered from the Microsoft Azure Service Bus.
```

How to register services on microsoft azure? 
I have installed microsoft azure powershell but it is not visible in startup.so, anyone having idea related to this error.

Answer (score 5):

> If you are finding it difficult to debug your remote event receiver,
>   most probably you would be using an incorrect connection string to
>   connect to the Microsoft Azure Service Bus. Visual Studio Error List
>   will show
>
> “**Cannot register Services/RemoteEventReceiver1.svc on Microsoft Azure
>   Service Bus: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal
>   Server Error**.”

Found [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepointdevelopersupport/2014/10/16/debugging-sharepoint-online-provider-hosted-app-remote-event-receivers/)

As per your question, it seems that you are trying to debug the RER. So you can follow [these](http://blog.virtosoftware.com/2014/12/creating-and-debugging-of-remote-event.html) steps.

You might have installed some wrong components or the installation might be incomplete.

For complete set up of RER, you can refer to [this](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/03/13/remote-event-receiver-rer-for-host-web-using-sharepoint-provider-hosted-app-in-office-365sharepoint-online-environment/).

**Edit:**

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28209550). You might get what you want.

Comment: I had follow same steps but after installing azure powershell not able to search in startup in windows 10?